# Error in GUI startup when launching GRASS GIS 7.8.4

Tags: grass-gis, error, gui

I have just installed the latest version of GRASS GIS(7.8.4) but it doesn't launch. I've tried reinstalling a few times and nothing seems to work. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
Starting GRASS GIS...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 1150, in OnInit
StartUp = GRASSStartup()
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 230, in __init__
self._set_properties(grassVersion, grassRevisionStr)
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 291, in _set_properties
self.OnSetDatabase(None)
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 927, in OnSetDatabase
self.OnSelectLocation(None)
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 862, in OnSelectLocation
self.lblocations.GetSelection()]))
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\gis_set.py", line 829, in UpdateMapsets
gisdbase=self.gisdbase)
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\gui\wxpython\core\gcmd.py", line 720, in RunCommand
stderr = decode(stderr)
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\etc\python\grass\script\utils.py", line 194, in decode
return bytes_.decode(enc)
File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2: character maps to 
<undefined>
OnInit returned false, exiting...
エラー: Error in GUI startup. See messages above (if any) and if necessary, please report this error 
to the GRASS developers.
On systems with package manager, make sure you have the right GUI package, probably named grass-gui, 
installed.
To run GRASS GIS in text mode use the --text flag.
Use '--help' for further options
 grass78 --help
See also: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/helptext.html
Exiting...
```

Comment: If you open **cp1252.py** file (as `"C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.8\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py"`) by a text editor and remove all UNDEFINED lines (which corresponds to `\ufffe`), could it fix UnicodeDecode Error, hopefully?